# Shorten an already short string in Java

Tags: java, string, encoding, compression

I'm looking for a way to shorten an already short string as much as possible.

The string is a hostname:port combo and could look like "*my-domain.se:2121*" or "*123.211.80.4:2122*".

I know regular compression is pretty much out of the question on strings this short due to the overhead needed and the lack of repetition but I have an idea of how to do it.

Because the alphabet is limited to 39 characters (*[a-z][0-9]-:.*) every character could fit in 6 bits. This reduce the length with up to 25% compared to ASCII. So my suggestion is somthing along these lines:

1. Encode the string to a byte array using some kind of custom encoding
2. Decode the byte array to a UTF-8 or ASCII string (this string will obviously not make any sense).

And then reverse the process to get the original string.

So to my questions:

1. Could this work?
2. Is there a better way?
3. How?

Comment: There is a 4th question you're missing: why?

Comment: You are limiting your application to only supporting Latin-1 characters?  How many of these values are you expecting to be storing?  Sounds to me like an awful lot of effort going into saving only a small amount of space.  Disk is cheap, developer/maintenance time is extremely expensive.

Comment: It's not about disk space. I need the to be as short as possible because the resulting string may be typed manually on a keyboard, phone, or spoken.

Comment: @Gustav, see, that's why you should always mention why. If you want to copy tinyurl, build your own (short) strings and map them to url addresses in a database. You can start at one letter strings and work your way up, for a low-to-medium traffic site you're unlikely to go past three characters.

Comment: @Blindy I didn't think it was actually needed. But you're right. The message is going to be transferred between two applications, so they don't have access to any kind of shared map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could encode the string as base 40 which is more compact than base 64. This will give you 12 such tokens into a 64 bit long. The 40th token could be the end of string marker to give you the length (as it will not be a whole number of bytes any more)

If you use arithmetic encoding, it could be much smaller but you would need a table of frequencies for each token. (using a long list of possible examples)

```
class Encoder {
  public static final int BASE = 40;
  StringBuilder chars = new StringBuilder(BASE);
  byte[] index = new byte[256];

  {
    chars.append('\0');
    for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) chars.append(ch);
    for (char ch = '0'; ch <= '9'; ch++) chars.append(ch);
    chars.append("-:.");
    Arrays.fill(index, (byte) -1);
    for (byte i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++)
      index[chars.charAt(i)] = i;
  }

  public byte[] encode(String address) {
    try {
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
      for (int i = 0; i < address.length(); i += 3) {
        switch (Math.min(3, address.length() - i)) {
          case 1: // last one.
            byte b = index[address.charAt(i)];
            dos.writeByte(b);
            break;

          case 2:
            char ch = (char) ((index[address.charAt(i+1)]) * 40 + index[address.charAt(i)]);
            dos.writeChar(ch);
            break;

          case 3:
            char ch2 = (char) ((index[address.charAt(i+2)] * 40 + index[address.charAt(i + 1)]) * 40 + index[address.charAt(i)]);
            dos.writeChar(ch2);
            break;
        }
      }
      return baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
    for (String s : "twitter.com:2122,123.211.80.4:2122,my-domain.se:2121,www.stackoverflow.com:80".split(",")) {
      System.out.println(s + " (" + s.length() + " chars) encoded is " + encoder.encode(s).length + " bytes.");
    }
  }
}
```

prints

```
twitter.com:2122 (16 chars) encoded is 11 bytes.
123.211.80.4:2122 (17 chars) encoded is 12 bytes.
my-domain.se:2121 (17 chars) encoded is 12 bytes.
www.stackoverflow.com:80 (24 chars) encoded is 16 bytes.
```

I leave decoding as an exercise. ;)

Comment: This was EXACTLY what I was looking for. Really struggling with the decoding part, but I should eventually get it working.

Comment: Read each pair of bytes as a char ch. The first index is `ch % 40`, the second is `ch / 40 % 40` and the last is `ch / 40 / 40`. Use `chars` to turn the index into a char. Note; I have swap the order in the code to make it simpler to decode. A `0` means you have reached the end.

Comment: Finally got it working. And it's absolutely beautiful :)
Thank you once again!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, IP addresses are designed to fit into 4 bytes and port numbers into 2.  The ascii representation is only for humans to read, so it doesn't make sense to do compression on that.

Your idea for compressing domain name strings is doable.

Comment: As you can see, it's not limited to IP addresses only. I need something that supports all the characters I mentioned.
I'm not sure where to begin if I'm doing it according to my idea =/

Answer (score 1):

Well in your case, I would use a specialized algo for your usecase. Recognize that you can store something other than strings. So for a IPv4 address : port, you would have a class that captured 6 bytes -- 4 for the address and 2 for the port. Another for type for apha-numeric hostnames. The port would always be stored in two bytes. The hostname part itself could also have specialized support for `.com`, for example. So a sample hierarchy may be:

```
    HostPort
       |
  +----+--------+
  |             |
IPv4        HostnamePort
                |
           DotComHostnamePort


public interface HostPort extends CharSequence { }


public HostPorts {
  public static HostPort parse(String hostPort) {
    ...
  }
}
```

In this case, the DotComHostnamePort allows you to drop `.com` from the host name and save 4 chars/bytes, depending on whether you store hostnames in punyform or in UTF16 form.

Comment: Not a bad idea... The only problem is that I need to send the used encoding method with the string.
But this would only require one additional byte, and as IP:port is going to be far more common, the string will be usually be quite a lot shorter...

Comment: What do you mean by 'send the used encoding method'? Do you mean you need to send the compressed form over some text based protocol? Because otherwise, you can transmit this in binary form; you would use a byte for each subtype, and each subtype would know how to serialize in the compressed form.

Comment: Yes the compressed form is going to be sent as text (or maybe even speech). But what i meant was that the "message" will need an extra character that indicates wether it contains a IPv4 address or a hostname.

Answer (score 1):

The first two bytes could contain the port number. If you always start with this fixed length port number, you don't need to include the separator `:`. Instead use a bit that indicates whether an IP address follows (see [Karl Bielefeldt's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389252/shorten-an-already-short-string-in-java/7389374#7389374) solution) or a host name.

Comment: This is probably what I'm gonna end up doing. Maybe I'll skip the host name compression. But it WOULD be great if I could manage that too.

Comment: I'm using this AND compressing the hostname (if it is used) with [Peter Lawrey's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389252/shorten-an-already-short-string-in-java/7390188#7390188) solution for string encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You could encode them using the [CDC Display code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDC_display_code). This encoding was used back in the old days when bits were scarce and programmers were nervous.

Comment: It looks like CDC actually contains all the characters I need!
I'm gonna look for Java implementations of this.

Comment: No success. Using Peter Lawrey's [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389252/shorten-an-already-short-string-in-java/7390188#7390188) instead as it saves even more space.

Answer (score 0):

What you are suggesting is similar to base 64 encoding/decoding and there might be some mileage in looking at some of those implementations (base 64 encoding uses 6 bits).

As a starter if you use Apaches base 64 library

```
String x = new String(Base64.decodeBase64("my-domain.se:2121".getBytes()));
String y = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(x.getBytes()));
System.out.println("x = " + x);
System.out.println("y = " + y);
```

It will shorten your string by a few chars. This obviously does not work as what you end up with is not what you started with.