# convert a string into the binary 64-bit block

Tags: java

I want to convert a string into the binary 64-bit block 
like if you enter the string testing 123 then output must be the binary equivalent of this with the 64 bit block.if any block less than 64 bit than append some random bit to it.

Comment: You need to specify more what you mean by "binary equivalent".

Comment: Are you looking for [base 64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)?

Comment: Are you suggesting UNICODE equivalence?

Comment: Are the strings always numbers? How many bits per character do you need? Are the strings always 0-9,a-z ? What assumptions can you have about the contents of the String?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think his sample input was "testing 123".

Comment: You can't use 6-bits per character and have a String of 11-characters fit in 64-bits.  You could encode eleven `[ 0-9a-z]` characters, but no more.

Comment: You can see my answer here which uses base 40. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389252/shorten-an-already-short-string-in-java/7390188#7390188

Answer (score 0):

The *net* package in *apache-commons* contains a class called Base64 that has a method *decode()* that seems to do what you want:

```
byte[]  decode(String pArray)
      Decodes a String containing containing characters in the Base64 alphabet.
```

Here's a link to the API:

http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/util/Base64.html

The maven dependency for the library is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This is the right idea but will need 66-bits to encode an 11 character strings such as `testing 123` BTW: base 64 doesn't allow spaces.

Comment: Ah, I thought he meant: if you enter the string "testing" and then the string "123". I'll leave my answer for now until this is clarified.